# Unable to install openjdk-8-jre-headless

Tags: linux, java

```
root@kvm6241 ~ # sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-8-jre-headless is a virtual package provided by:
  oracle-java17-installer 17.0.6-1~linuxuprising0
  oracle-java11-installer-local 11.0.18-1~linuxuprising0
You should explicitly select one to install.
```

I already update and upgrade the terminal. What would I do next?

Comment: Which part of `You should explicitly select one to install.` is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

```
virtual package provided by: 
oracle-java17-installer 17.0.6-1~linuxuprising0 
oracle-java11-installer-local 11.0.18-1~linuxuprising0 
You should explicitly select one to install.
```

Which actually means you have to feed exactly package name which is listed for required package as it's virtual you need to install provider package. Try below command.

`sudo apt install oracle-java17-installer`

Comment: when i write this commend 
"sudo apt install  oracle-java11-installer-local"
please download the Oracle JDK 11 .tar.gz file
with the same version as this package (version 11.0.4),
and place it in /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local,




can you send me commends to downlond that version